# Unable to decrypt using Blowfish

Tags: python, pycrypto

I am using Python3 and PyCrypto module for Blowfish Algorithm. I am able to encrypt when i give the key and plaintext via command line but i am unable to decrypt. However, the code is working correctly if I use it in Python Interpreter.

ENCRYPTION (blowfish_encr.py)

```
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
from Crypto import Random
from struct import pack
import sys

bs = Blowfish.block_size
key = sys.argv[1].encode()
iv = Random.new().read(bs)
cipher = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv)

plaintext = sys.argv[2].encode()
plen = bs - divmod(len(plaintext),bs)[1]
padding = [plen]*plen
padding = pack('b'*plen, *padding)

msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintext + padding)
print(msg)
```

DECRYPTION (blowfish_decr.py)

```
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
from struct import pack
import sys

bs = Blowfish.block_size
ciphertext = sys.argv[2].encode()
key = sys.argv[1].encode()

iv = ciphertext[:bs]
ciphertext = ciphertext[bs:]
cipher = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv)
msg = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
last_byte = msg[-1]

msg = msg[:- (last_byte if type(last_byte) is int else ord(last_byte))]
print(repr(msg))
```

OUTPUT:

> $python3 blowfish_encr.py key 'Test it!'

```
b'\xf8\x1eK)\x81?\xa2\x88\x01\x16\x8e\xdc\xe5\xb9\xd8_K\xce\x03\xe4\x88g\xf8\xa1'
```

> $python3 blowfish_decr.py key '\xf8\x1eK)\x81?\xa2\x88\x01\x16\x8e\xdc\xe5\xb9\xd8_K\xce\x03\xe4\x88g\xf8\xa1'

```
  File "blowfish_decr.py", line 12, in <module>
   msg = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 295, in decrypt
   return self._cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
  ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 8 in length
```

How to get it decrypted ? I know the error is because when I input the encoded text as a string it converts all the `\` to `\\` , and when I try `sys.argv[2].encode().replace('\\','\')` it it doesn't work because `\'` is `a string literal`.

How to get it done using the command line argument?

Comment: This is probably happening because the shell is interpreting the backlashes and the input python ends up getting is already wrong. I would try using an ASCII safe binary encoding such as base64 instead.

Comment: python3 base64 does not allow to encode strings. it need bytes-like objects to encode to b64 encoding.

Comment: The resulting `msg` in your encryption is a bytes object, isn't it? Encode that into base-64.